# Countdown timer does not stop when activity change

Tags: java, android, eclipse, performance, countdowntimer

I have used class which have timer function. So i can reuse that code everytime whenever i want. Problem is when i move from one activity to another activity then timer should be reset but timer could not be finished and new timer will be start again. Here is my code

```
public class Utils {
    Context mContext;

    private static final String TAG = Utils.class.getSimpleName();
    CountDownTimer mCountDownTimer = null;
    boolean isRunning = false;
    private Activity activityContext;

    public Utils(Context context) {
        this.mContext = context;
        this.activityContext = (Activity) context;
    }

public void resetTimer() {

        if (isRunning) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Timer is stopping now..######");
            mCountDownTimer.cancel();
            mCountDownTimer = null;
            isRunning = false;
            startCountDownTimer();

        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "Timer is starting now..######");
            startCountDownTimer();

        }

    }

    public void stopCountDownTimer() {

        if (mCountDownTimer != null) {

            mCountDownTimer.cancel();
            mCountDownTimer = null;

        }

    }

    public void startCountDownTimer() {

        mCountDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(10000, 1000) {

            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Timer is ticking..!!!!");

                isRunning = true;

            }

            public void onFinish() {
                Log.d(TAG, "Timer is finished..!!!!");
                isRunning = false;

                try {

                    Intent launchIntent = mContext.getPackageManager()
                            .getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.#########.###");
                    activityContext.startActivity(launchIntent);
                    activityContext.finish();
                    System.exit(0);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

        }.start();

    }
}
```

In activity create method i call this `resetTimer()` but timer does not reset. I also call `stopCountDownTimer()` and result will be same. What am i missing here ?

**SOLVED :**

```
    public class Utils {
        Context mContext;

        private static final String TAG = Utils.class.getSimpleName();
        CountDownTimer mCountDownTimer = null;
        boolean isRunning = false;
        private Activity activityContext;

        private final long startTime = 10 * 1000;

        private final long interval = 1 * 1000;

        public Utils(Context context) {
            this.mContext = context;
            this.activityContext = (Activity) context;
            mCountDownTimer = new MyCountDownTimer(startTime, interval);
        }

    public void resetTimer() {

            if (isRunning) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Timer is stopping now..######");
                mCountDownTimer.cancel();
                mCountDownTimer = null;
                mCountDownTimer = new MyCountDownTimer(startTime, interval);
                isRunning = false;
                Log.d(TAG, "Timer is stopped amd starting again..######");
                mCountDownTimer.start();
                // startCountDownTimer();

            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "Timer is starting now..######");
                // startCountDownTimer();
                mCountDownTimer.start();

            }

        }
    }
    public void stopCountDownTimer() {

        if (mCountDownTimer != null) {

            mCountDownTimer.cancel();
            mCountDownTimer = null;

        }

    }

    public class MyCountDownTimer extends CountDownTimer {
        public MyCountDownTimer(long startTime, long interval) {
            super(startTime, interval);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            Log.d(TAG, "Timer is finished..!!!!");
            isRunning = false;

            try {

                Intent launchIntent = mContext.getPackageManager()
                        .getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.####.####");
                activityContext.startActivity(launchIntent);
                activityContext.finish();
                System.exit(0);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Timer is ticking..!!!!");

            //Toast.makeText(mContext, ""+millisUntilFinished/1000, 50).show();
            isRunning = true;

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: How did you instantiate your Utils class? How did you ensure it is Singleton?

Comment: where is the @Override annotaion for onTick() and onFinish() ?

Comment: If i extend any class with CountDownTimer then Override method will generate but i just simply use this function. @Opiatefuchs

Comment: try adding 

mCountDownTimer.cancel();
mCountDownTimer = null;
isRunning = false;

into your onFinish() method...
and do not call reset or stop methods of countdown timer.

Comment: I have changed function to class and now it works fine.. thanks though @AditiParikh